# Sql Query converted to sql table with opening qnt. purchase qnt, and closing qnt

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables M_Stock1

[image]

and M_Table

[image]

```
SELECT 
    t1.Date,
    mt.M_Name,
    (SELECT Opening_Stock FROM [M_Table] WHERE M_Id = t1.M_Id) +
    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(t2.Purchase_Qnt - t2.Sales_Qnt) FROM [M_Stock1] t2
     WHERE t2.Date < t1.Date AND t1.M_Id = t2.M_Id), 0) AS Opening_Stock,
    t1.Purchase_Qnt,
    t1.Sales_Qnt,
    (SELECT Opening_Stock FROM [M_Table] WHERE M_Id = t1.M_Id) +
    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(t2.Purchase_Qnt - t2.Sales_Qnt) FROM [M_Stock1] t2
     WHERE t2.Date <= t1.Date AND t1.M_Id = t2.M_Id), 0) AS Closing_Stock
FROM [M_Stock1] t1
left outer JOIN [M_Table] mt
    ON t1.M_Id = mt.M_Id
ORDER BY
    mt.M_Name,
    t1.Date;
```

Code I used for result

[image]

I am getting query result good
but my problem is I need this result as table instead of Query

Comment: Use `into` or `create table as` depending on the database you are using.

Comment: Guessing that's SQL Server, but do you mean table, a view or something else? Your question is pretty unclear